# Extra padding in HorizontalPager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to handle Horizontal Pager but I'm having a problem with additional padding from the top. It only happens when I add `HorizontalPager()` to my layout.

As you can see in the attachment I have grey indicators which I want to put below my pager but when I do that Pager goes lower and indicators become invisible. It looks like `HorizontalPager()` has some top padding (?)

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(350.dp)
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(0.dp, 0.dp, 12.dp, 12.dp))
        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground)
) {
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        val (backButton, favouriteButton, photosPager) = createRefs()

        BackNavigationSingleButton(
            backButtonSelected = { }, modifier = Modifier
                .height(42.dp)
                .width(60.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                .background(Color.Red)
                .constrainAs(backButton) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                }
        )

        IconButton(onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier
            .size(42.dp)
            .constrainAs(favouriteButton) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            }) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Favorite
            )
        }


        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(photosPager) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                }) {
            val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
            val items = 3
            HorizontalPager(
                count = items,
                state = pagerState,
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
            ) { page ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(100.dp)
                        .background(Color.Green)
                )
            }

            Row(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)) {
                for (i in 1..items) {
                    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp)) {
                        drawCircle(
                            color =  Color.Gray,
                            center = Offset(x = 10f, y = 10f),
                            radius = size.minDimension / 4,
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You said that you want your indicators "put below my pager" - yet they are shown at the top of the pager. So which is it? You want the indicators at the top "above" the pager, or  at the bottom "below" the pager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each page inside `HorizontalPager` is using [`Modifier.fillParentMaxSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyItemScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillParentMaxSize(kotlin.Float)), which makes it fill all available height, same what `Modifier.fillMaxHeight` does.

When `Column` has an item with `Modifier.fillMaxHeight`, this item will push all next items. To prevent this you can use [`Modifier.weight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).weight(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)): in this case height of this view will be calculated after all other `Column` children.

---

Also most of time `ConstraintLayout` is redundant in Compose, here's how you can build same layout without it:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(350.dp)
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(0.dp, 0.dp, 12.dp, 12.dp))
        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground.copy(0.5f))
        .padding(10.dp)
) {
    Row {
        TextButton(
            onClick = { },
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                .background(Color.Red)
        ) {
            Text("button")
        }
        Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
        IconButton(
            onClick = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(42.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Favorite,
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }
    }

    Column {
        val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
        val items = 3
        HorizontalPager(
            count = items,
            state = pagerState,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        ) { page ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .background(Color.Green)
            )
        }

        Row(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)) {
            for (i in 1..items) {
                Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp)) {
                    drawCircle(
                        color = Color.Gray,
                        center = Offset(x = 10f, y = 10f),
                        radius = size.minDimension / 4,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer. Work fine but I'm a little confused about that. I tried to move green box more to the top and indicators closer to green box but it doesn't work at all. How I can do that? I tried to change weight in all components but as I said it doesn't work :/

Comment: @Wafi_ck how have you tried? You can use `Modifier.padding` or `Modifier.offset`